# How to access fields of @EmbeddedId?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an `@Entity` that has a composite primary key. Therefore I created an `@EmbeddedId` holding the PK fields.

Question: is it better to access those fields by `id.*` directly, or should I create getter/setter in the parent class?

Example:

```
@Entity
public class MyPerson {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonId id;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return id.getFirstname();   
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return id.getLastname();
    }

    public LocalDate getDob() {
        return id.getDob();
    }   
}

@Embeddable
public class PersonId implements Serializable {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private LocalDate dob;

    //getter+setter as well
}
```

Should I better use `person.getFistname()` or `person.getId().getFirstname()`?

The former is more clear, but with the drawback that I'd have to create the getters both in `MyPerson` and in `PersonId`.

What should be the preferred way to access, and why?

Comment: This might be a matter of preference but I would say don't provide getters and setters in the parent class. What if the fields change in the embedded class? Some might result in compile error but what if you add a field to it and forget to wrap the getter/setter in the parent class? Personally I use the getters and setters on the embedded class, so do `person.getId().getFirstName()`

Comment: I wonder if there is also anything in the JPA spec about it?http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html Can't see anything myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to create property

```
private PersonId id
```

Alternative is

```
@Entity  @IdClass(PersonId.class)
public class MyPerson {
    @Id private String firstname;
    @Id private String lastname;
    @Id private LocalDate dob;

    // Getters and setters here    
}
```

And use PersonId only for loading *MyPerson* entities:

```
PersonId peronId = new PersonId(firstname, lastname, dob);
MyPerson person = session.get(MyPerson.class, personId);
```

Comment: But that would mean I'd have the fields including getter+setter duplicated? Both in the `MyPerson` and in `PersonId`, right? If so - is it really advisable? Imagine each property has additional configurations like `@NotNull @Length(min=10, max=20) @Column(nullable=false, length=20) private String firstname`. I then would have to maintain that configurations on both sides?

Comment: This configuration must be only on entity side. Key class can be without any annotations.