# How to expose fields of and @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lombok

I have an `@Entity` with three fields A, B, C out of which A and B act as composite primary key. I created an `@EmbeddedId` class holding A and B. To ease the burden of defining getters and setters i used lombok `@Data` annotation.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class MyClass {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PrimaryKey id;
}

@Embeddable
@Data
public class PrimareyKey implements Serializable {
    private String A;
    private String B;
}
```

I would not like to expose that A and B are the primary key and access A and access all fields in the same way.

```
//Exposes primary key
myObject.getid().getA();
myObject.getid().getB();
myObject.getC();

//Hides primary key
myObject.getA();
myObject.getB();
myObject.getC();
```

Currently one could use `@IdClass` tagging each filed as `@Id` as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075807/how-to-access-fields-of-embeddedid) but if I still need to use `@EmbeddedId` (or any `@Embedded` actually) the only way (I know) to achieve this is to write ad hoc getters and setters bypassing the id variable such as

```
@Entity
@Data
public class MyClass {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PrimaryKey id;

    public String A getA(){
        return id.getA()
    }

    public String A setA(String a){
        id.setA(a);
    }
    //same for B and any other fiels in PrimaryKey

}
```

This looks like a lot of boilerplate code to write and maintain.

Is there an annotation to expose `@EmbeddedId` getters and setters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MyClass, add Lombok `@Delegate` annotation to your PrimaryKey. It should look like:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class MyClass {
    @Delegate
    @EmbeddedId
    private PrimaryKey id;
}
```

Then you can set/get PrimaryKey fields directly from MyClass. [Here](https://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html) is a link for you to read more about it.

Comment: As reported [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate)  the annotation is now marked as experimental and support might be removed in future version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AccessLevel with @Getter and @Setter as follows:

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private PrimaryKey id;
```

When using @Data, you have the public access to accessors by default, and using AccessLevel.NONE will overwrite the default behaviour and will not allow to access the accessors.

Comment: My question was more related to proxy access to PrimaryKey fields directly from MyClass but still this is a nice way to hide the PrimaryKey at all if needed. Should be used in conjunction with @Delegate as pointed out in the next answer